# Random domain pointing to my domain

Tags: domains, htaccess, redirects, google-search

A random person has pointed their domain to my website. I don't have much experience with websites, but I know a bit.
What can I put in `.htaccess` to give a 403 error if they try to access from a certain domain?

And I would also need to block the other pages in my site showing up on Google,
e.g. `mysite.com/help`

Sorry if I phrased that strangely, I don't know the correct terminology.

This is my `.htaccess` so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?nameofmysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you give use more detail on how these domains a *pointed* to your domain?? For example, are the setting the domain name to your IP address? Or are they using redirect? This makes a difference in how you would approach the problem.

Comment: Im not that experienced with this sorry but from Who.Is it says it is Type A and linked to my IP

Comment: I have managed to block the domain reaching the site through .htaccess, but it is still the very first 5 results in google when I search my site, all the results are sub pages in my domain, like /forums and /about, im using the code RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?nameofmysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: I am not sure why people do this. There is no actual benefit or payoff. Depending upon how your server is set-up, this would not normally be a problem since it would not work. However, not all web server installs have a default site which would be a junk blank site. If you are effectively blocking the site (I prefer redirecting to a porn or spam site), then it is a matter of time when G makes it right again. There is nothing you can do to hurry the process up. Sorry. You can at least do a Fetch as Google for the top pages and Submit to Index in Google Search Console if you have an account.

Comment: If you use Fetch as Google, keep in mind that this is not immediate and still can take a couple of days. These things happen from time to time. I rather suspect that it is a very lazy domain monetizer. This does not work very well so I am not sure why they do this. It is just a matter of time before Google marks the pages found on the second domain as duplicate and ranks your site properly again. You can also use canonical tags on all of your pages with full URLs that point to your page. This stops this dead too and is an ounce of prevention for the future.

Comment: Related: [Someone else is using my IP address with an old A Record. What can i do?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85682/someone-else-is-using-my-ip-address-with-an-old-a-record-what-can-i-do)